# Add external javascript file to Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

I've tried the same approach on Magento 2.1.7 and Magento 2.2.1 and it worked in M2.1.7 but not M2.2.1 unless something else is going on...

The approach I used was to edit `default_head_blocks.xml` in directory 
`app/design/frontend/<VENDOR_NAME>/<MODULE_NAME>/Magento_Theme/layout` which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/smartlook.js" />
        <!-- Also tried: <script src="Magento_Theme::js/smartlook.js" />  -->
    </head>
</page>
```

On Magento 2.1.7 I can see this file in the `<head>` section, but it doesn't seem to show up in Magento 2.2.1 after doing

`setup:upgrade`
`cache:flush`
`setup:di:compile`
`setup:static-content:deploy -f`

**Update**

Either `js/smartlook.js` or `Magento_Theme::js/smartlook.js` my problem was a silly mistake :/

Comment: please assign module namespace in script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Namespace_Modulename before js declaration in script tag.

Now your js file will be at location,

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Modulename}/view/frontend/web/js/smartlook.js

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Namespace_Modulename::js/jscolor.min.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**Replace {Namespace}/{Modulename} with your actuall module name path.**

Comment: set <script src="Magento_Theme::js/jscolor.min.js"/> and run upgrade command